# GeneratorExit in while loop

Tags: python

I am not clear about the behavior of catching GeneratorExit in a while loop, here is my code:

```
# python 
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep  4 2013, 07:46:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def func():
...     while True:
...         try:
...             yield 9
...         except GeneratorExit:
...             print "Need to do some clean up."
... 
>>> g = func()
>>> g.next()
9
>>> g.close()
Need to do some clean up.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

It appears when g.close() is called, GeneratorExit is catched because "Need to do some clean up." is printed, but I do not understand why there is a RuntimeError.

Comment: For those who come across this, you might accidentally be doing `try: yield some_operation(foo); except: pass`. You'd think this would be ignoring errors in some_operation, but it's actually also ignoring an early-exit GeneratorExit triggered by the call site you're yielding to! Instead, try-except some_operation and yield after that try-except. Or handle a smaller-scoped exception!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**"It appears when g.close() is called, GeneratorExit is catched"**

Yes, GeneratorExit is raised when the generator's close() method is called.

See the following documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

And the exception will cause a RuntimeError

After the aforementioned exception is raised inside the loop, it is actually handled, and you see the printed error message. But, the loop continues, and it still tries to yield 9. That's when you see the RuntimeError. Therefore, moving the exception handling outside of your loop solves the problem.

Comment: But if I catch GeneratorExit outside of the while loop, then I will not see that RuntimeError, seems everything works fine.

Comment: @Eric   Added another clarification.

Answer (score 9):

Just add a `return` statement after printing `"Need to do some clean up."`. Everything works fine then :). This the preferred way, esp when you cannot move your exception out

```
while True:
    try:
        yield 9
     except GeneratorExit:
        print "Need to do some clean up."
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

You're catching the exception inside the loop, so even though it receives the exception, it still tries to `yield` a value in the next iteration.

Move the exception handling outside of the loop.